# Adding objects to ArrayList from TreeMap Based on key constraints

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, collections, treemap

I am working on requirement where I need to add individual responseItems to arrayList from a TreeMap. I have object array of Map keys (String type) . responseCodes can have values of 1-15 and "NA".

Based on below conditions ( on keys) I have to fetch responseItems from Map and add to ArrayList..

1) If Response code is "NA" or "0" and I dont need to add responseItem to my arrayList.

2) If Response code is "1" I have to add responseItems with the the responseCode value "2".

3) If Response code is any value between (2-15) ,I have to add all other responseItems with the responseCode value grater than currentResponse code in array.

I have implemented this using some nested for loops and I am assuming that this can be done in efficient manner.Kindly go through the requirement and below code snippet and help me on this.

```
public List getResponseItemList(Object [] responseCodeArray){

    List itemsList = new ArrayList();

    if (responseCodeArray != null && responseCodeArray.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= responseCodeArray.length; i++) {
            if (!((responseCodeArray[responseCodeArray.length - i]
                    .equals("NA")) | (responseCodeArray[responseCodeArray.length
                    - i].equals("0")))) {

                if (responseCodeArray[responseCodeArray.length - i]
                        .equals("1")) {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= responseCodeArray.length; j++) {
                        if ((responseCodeArray[responseCodeArray.length - j]
                                .equals("2"))) {
                            itemsList = itemsByResponseCodeMap
                                    .get(responseCodeArray[responseCodeArray.length
                                            - j]);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    int level = Integer
                            .parseInt((String) responseCodeArray[responseCodeArray.length
                                    - i]);
                    for (int x = 1; x <= responseCodeArray.length; x++) {
                        int innerLevel = Integer
                                .parseInt((String) responseCodeArray[responseCodeArray.length
                                        - x]);
                        if (innerLevel > level) {
                            itemsList = itemsByResponseCodeMap
                                    .get(responseCodeArray[responseCodeArray.length
                                            - x]);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        Collections.sort(itemsList);// for sorting
        return itemsList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using raw types here, out of interest?

Comment: why are you starting your loop counters with value 1? You'll have IndexOutOfBoundException..

Comment: With this : `for (int i = 1; i <= responseCodeArray.length; i++)` you skip the first element of your array and you are doing a bitewise OR here `((responseCodeArray[responseCodeArray.length - i]
                    .equals("NA")) | (responseCodeArray[responseCodeArray.length
                    - i].equals("0")))` instead of a boolean OR. And can you be more specific on what is going wrong ?

Comment: With i=1 It wont skip first element since I am iterating from last element of array...i.e (responseCodeArray[responseCodeArray.length - i])... The reason for using bitwise OR is I dont want to step into for loop if element value is either "0" or "NA"..  Coming to the problem I would like to go for better implementation than this.. Its working fine..But can I optimise nested for loop? any idea ?